# Laravel Excel validation import

Tags: excel, laravel, validation, import

I am using the Maatwebsite/excel component to import excel files. In this case, importing users. I need to validate that the mail does not exist and then import the unique data

I have this code in the import file

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithValidation
{
    use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $row[0],
            'email'    => $row[1], 
            'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
        ]);

        $user->assignRole('guest');
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '0' => 'required|string',
            '1' => 'unique:users',
        ];
    }

}
```

And this code in my controller:

```
public function import() 
{
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file('file'));

    return back()->with('success', 'Importado con éxito!');
}
```

When I want to import duplicate data, I get the following error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1.1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `1`.`1` = admin@adsmdfin.com)

Comment: Follow this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769433/laravel-excel-validation** Link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The validator's exist rule will use the key of the array (1 in your case) as the column to search inside the users table.

You can specify the column like this and it should work.

```
'1' => 'unique:users,email',
```

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists

Comment: Excelent! that was

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithValidation
{
    use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        '1' => 'unique:users,email'
    ];

}

public function customValidationMessages()
{
    return [
        '1.unique' => 'Correo ya esta en uso.',
    ];
}

public function model(array $row)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name'     => $row[0],
        'email'    => $row[1], 
        'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
    ]);

    $user->assignRole('guest');
}


}
```